# ZyWALL USG 200 - dynamic DNS for clients

Tags: networking, router, zyxel

What do I need to do on ZyWALL USG-200, so every time DHCP server assigns IP address to client, it also creates DNS entry in the local domain for it.

Thanks,
Radek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got an answer on Zyxel forum directly:

http://forum.zyxel.com/viewtopic.php?f=14&t=2618

Unfortunately, this feature is not possible with current firmware :(